# Gno-Menu appears multiple times (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have GNOME Tweaks installed on Ubuntu 18.04 and I use the Gno-Menu (version 3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1).  When I first boot up, I see one Menu button in the lower left, as it should be.  After some indeterminate time and event (usually a couple days), multiple Gno-Menu's appear on the taskbar:

[image: Screenshot showing problem]

A reboot will clear them back to one.

Within the GNOME Extensions menu, after the problem begins, the Gno-Menu is shown as off and has an exclamation mark with the hover text "Error Loading Extension":

[image: Tweaks Menu]

Similarly, on the Appearance tab of the GNOME Extensions menu, Shell has an exclamation mark and says "Shell user-theme extension not enabled" (this may be unrelated).

Running "killall -3 gnome-shell" also successfully resets the menu.

Comment: This might be extensions not working well together. To eliminate that possibility, disable all other extensions than dash-to-panel and gnomenu to see if the problem still appears. Does it also happen if you do not use dash-to-panel?

Comment: The problem did show up sometime after I started using dash-to-panel so it could be related to that.  When I disactivate dash-to-panel while the problem is occurring, the problem continues to occur but once gno-menu has crashed, that action may be too late to be useful.  I'll turn it off prior to gno-menu crashing and test.  Also turned off the only other activated extension (Touchpad Indicator).  Will probably be a couple days before I repost unless the problem recurs earlier.

Comment: @vanadium: I left dash-to-panel off for about four days without a problem.  I then turned it back on again and the problem resurfaced within two days so it appears we have a link.  Assuming this is extensions not playing well together, are there any mitigating steps I can take or is de-activation of extensions the only option (short of periodically running "killall -3 gnome-shell").

Comment: Extensions not working well together indeed, but not easy to reproduce: you decribe it takes sometimes days before the issue appears. Many users, especially laptop users, will be less likely to have the system up sufficiently long to see the issue. Arch menu is another quite powerful "traditional" menu you may want to try.

Comment: Thanks, @vanadium.  I have switched over to Arc Menu as they are functionally the same.